# Pinescript correlation(source_a, source_b, length) -> to python

Tags: python, data-analysis, pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I need help with translating pine correlation function to python, I've already translated stdev and swma functions, but this one is a bit confusing for me.

I've also found this explanation but didn't quite understand how to implement it:

> in python try using `pandas` with `.rolling(window).corr` where `window` is
>   the correlation coefficient period, `pandas` allow you to compute any
>   rolling statistic by using `rolling()`. The correlation coefficient from
>   pine is calculated with : `sma(y*x,length) - sma(y,length)*sma(x,length)` divided by
>   `stdev(length*y,length)*stdev(length*x,length)` where `stdev` is based on
>   the naïve algorithm.

Pine documentation for this func:

```
> Correlation coefficient. Describes the degree to which two series tend
> to deviate from their sma values. correlation(source_a, source_b,
> length) → series[float] RETURNS Correlation coefficient.
```

ARGUMENTS

`source_a` (series) Source series.

`source_b` (series) Target series.

`length` (integer) Length (number of bars back).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pandas is indeed the best option, TA-Lib also has a `CORREL` function. In order for you to get a better idea of how the `correlation` function in pine is implemented here is a python code making use of numpy, note that this is not an efficient solution.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def sma(src,m):
    coef = np.ones(m)/m
    return np.convolve(src,coef,mode="valid")

def stdev(src,m):
    a = sma(src*src,m)
    b = np.power(sma(src,m),2)
    return np.sqrt(a-b)

def correlation(x,y,m):
    cov = sma(x*y,m) - sma(x,m)*sma(y,m)
    den = stdev(x,m)*stdev(y,m)
    return cov/den

ts = np.random.normal(size=500).cumsum()
n = np.linspace(0,1,len(ts))
cor = correlation(ts,n,14)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(ts)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(cor)
plt.show()
```